# Getting this error on macOS Monterey: Code signing "AppAuth.framework" failed

Tags: ios, xcode, signing, macos-monterey

An screenshot of the error is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VckH8.png)

It happens when trying to upload the app to Apple Connect from Xcode after achieving.

Here are the logs: IDEDistributionPipeline.log

```
2021-06-18 05:59:30 +0000  Running /usr/bin/codesign '-vvv' '--force' '--sign' '93D0804B68D64BEB32D3E27D45905B528D468CAE' '--entitlements' '/var/folders/l9/lc4s2hls2vg03bs4g3bct1d00000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.~~~1slhOn/entitlements~~~OmmxKx' '--preserve-metadata=identifier,flags,runtime' '/var/folders/l9/lc4s2hls2vg03bs4g3bct1d00000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.~~~1slhOn/Root/Payload/Belen.app/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework'
2021-06-18 05:59:30 +0000  /var/folders/l9/lc4s2hls2vg03bs4g3bct1d00000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.~~~1slhOn/Root/Payload/Belen.app/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework: internal error in Code Signing subsystem
2021-06-18 05:59:30 +0000  /usr/bin/codesign exited with 1
```

I'm importing this framework using CocoaPods.

*Any ideas how can I fix this issue?*

I've been struggling with this error for over a week.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you use macOS Monterey? I startded having this issue after upgrade

Comment: @АндрейКостенко Yes, this is a known issue. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue on macOS Monterrey. Apple engineers are working on it.

My workaround was to simply use another Mac with macOS Big Sur and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it might be good for us to know how you added AppAuth to your project. CocoaPods? Carthage? How exactly?

I think you also added the Framework wrong in your Xcode project by asking Xcode to "Embed and Sign" it, even though that framework is not your own code.

To change that setting open your project, select your apps target, go to the General tab and then scroll down to "Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content". Look for AppAuth.framework and change the selection to "Do Not Embed". This should do the trick.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't work :|
I'm using CocoaPods :)

Comment: Any other ideas? :( @JanBrinker

Comment: Not directly, but I'll tell you how I would debug this. Try to build a new test version without AppAuth. So remove AppAuth from the Podfile, run pod install, remove all the AppAuth reliant code from the project, build and try to upload. (Just for testing purposes.) If the upload succeeds: then there must be an issue with the way you added AppAuth. If it fails with the same reason for another dependency: there's an issue with your whole Pods setup. If if fails with a different reason it would be very strange but it might also offer clues. Try this and post your results. Maybe I can help.

Comment: Wondering if you were able to fix this @AntonioAsapche, I'm having the same issue

Comment: @NavjeevenMann check out my answer.